# Qt qml error ipv6 network on iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, qt, qml, ipv6

My app has been refused by apple because it dont support ipv6 network.

Here is the mail from apple :

> Performance - 2.1
>
> We discovered one or more bugs in your app when reviewed on iPad and
>   iPhone running iOS 10.0.2 on Wi-Fi connected to an IPv6 network.
>
> Specifically, when we attempted ti log into your app with the provided
>   credentials, your app displayed an activity indicator that spanned
>   indefinitely.
>
> The steps to reproduce are:
>
> 1. Launch your app
> 2. Enter demo account information
> 3. App shows activity indicator that spins indefinitely
>
> We've attached screenshot(s) for your reference.
>
> Next Steps
>
> Please run your app on a device while connected to an IPv6 network
>   (all apps must support IPv6) to identify the issue(s), then revise and
>   resubmit your app for review.
>
> If we misunderstood the intended behavior of your app, please reply to
>   this message in Resolution Center to provide information on how these
>   features were intended to work.
>
> For new apps, uninstall all previous versions of your app from a
>   device, then install and follow the steps to reproduce the issue(s).
>   For updates, install the new version as an update to the previous
>   version, then follow the steps to reproduce the issue(s).
>
> Resources
>
> For information about supporting IPv6 Networks, please refer to
>   Supporting IPv6 DNS64/NAT64 Networks and About Networking
>   https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/NetworkingInternetWeb/Conceptual/NetworkingOverview/UnderstandingandPreparingfortheIPv6Transition/UnderstandingandPreparingfortheIPv6Transition.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010220-CH213-SW1
>
> If you have difficulty reproducing a reported issue, please try
>   testing the workflow described in Technical Q&A QA1764: How to
>   reproduce bugs reported against App Store submissions.
>
> If you have code-level questions after utilizing the above resources,
>   you may wish to consult with Apple Developer Technical Support. When
>   the DTS engineer follows up with you, please be ready to provide:
>   - complete details of your rejection issue(s)
>   - screenshots
>   - steps to reproduce the issue(s)
>   - symbolicated crash logs - if your issue results in a crash log

I use this code when a user try to connect on the app :

```
  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
         xhr.onreadystatechange=function() {
             if (xhr.readyState == XMLHttpRequest.DONE && xhr.status == 200) {
                 connect(xhr.responseText);
             }
         }
         xhr.open('POST', url, true);
         var params = "login="+login.text+"&password="+pass.text;

        // Send the proper header information along with the request
         xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
         xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-length", params.length);
         xhr.setRequestHeader("Connection", "close");

         xhr.send(params);
```

But I dont really saw a solution to my problem if someone can help me

Maybe this is a part of the solution : http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qnetworkaccessmanager.html     ? or do I have to change something on the info.plist ?

Comment: They just told me to look at this : https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/NetworkingInternetWeb/Conceptual/NetworkingOverview/UnderstandingandPreparingfortheIPv6Transition/UnderstandingandPreparingfortheIPv6Transition.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010220-CH213-SW1
If I understand I just need to do some change on Info.plist, am i right ?

Comment: They sent me the error, how to reproduce it and some ressources (link above, to contact the tech support)

Comment: OK, now we're getting somewhere. What happened when you tried it on the NAT64 test network that they advised you to create?

Comment: When I launch the app and i try to connect, the indicator spin indefinitely as the mail say

Comment: Did you do something obvious like use an IPv4 address literal? That's the sort of behavior I would expect to see in that case.

Comment: I did anything like this